# File permission error on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, sendmail, host

I Am using `send grid` for `codeigniter`. My target is send `pdf` mail.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
>
> Message: Unable to open http://website.com/projectdemo/webusa/uploads/files/ash.pdf for reading
>
> Filename:opt/lampp/htdocs/projectdemo/webusa/application/third_party/sendEmail/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/PostFile.php
>
> Line Number: 53

My PHP Code:-

```
$pdfFilePath = HOSTNAME."uploads/files/ash.pdf";
 $this->sendMail($to, $subject, $message , $pdfFilePath );
```

Comment: is upload in root ?? or inside application folder??

Comment: root/application/uploads/file

Comment: Check My answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can not access a file with its `HTTP` path. Change it to the absolute path like below

```
root_directory/path/to/file/residing/ash.pdf

eg(local machine): D://my_folder/myfiles/ash.pdf
eg(live server): /public_html/myfiles/ash.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to post a file to a remote location, Guzzle requires that file to be local. You should look into downloading the file at `http://website.com/projectdemo/webusa/uploads/files/ash.pdf` and then uploading it.

If you are not keen on downloading the whole file into a temporary location and then uploading it back, one possible solution would be to use streams.

Have a look at this discussion as well:

- [Copy remote file using Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939794/copy-remote-file-using-guzzle)

Comment: The file is downloaded on this link but error at sending mail time. as well as this file also read on web page. http://website.com/projectdemo/webusa/uploads/files/ash.pdf

Comment: The file should be local. You need to download the file at the filesystem the script runs in order to attach it to the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**If inside application folder**

```
$pdfFilePath = APPPATH."uploads/files/ash.pdf";
```

**If Outside application folder**

```
$pdfFilePath = base_url()."uploads/files/ash.pdf";
```

Comment: Show me `$pdfFilePath` value